# Additional Get methods in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Consider i need to have three Get methods ProductController.

1)GetProducts()

2)GetProducts(int id)

3)GetProductsForDiscount()

The 3rd method i couldnt access it. It is not displayed in swagger at all.

https://ibb.co/jDnSRm

Comment: specify the route

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for RESTful APIs is to have noun based URLs with the action defined by standard HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc.) The URL defines the resource (in this case Products) and the verb defines the action (GET = read). Parameters allow you to control what is returned to the caller.

A common way to achieve this in ASP.NET WebApi is via attribute routing. You can define how the ASP runtime should select your controller action based on the query string parameters.

For example:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        /*
         * Code to get products here.
         */
        return Ok<IEnumerable<Product>>(products);
    }

    [Route("api/product/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        /*
         * Code to get product here.
         */
        return Ok<Product>(product);
    }

    [Route("api/product/{forDiscount:bool}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(bool forDiscount)
    {
        /*
         * Code to get discounted products here.
         */
        return Ok<IEnumerable<Product>>(products);
    }

}
```

When this controller is called, the actions will be selected as follows:

- /product - First action which returns a list of products.
- /product/123 - Second action which returns product with ID = 123.
- /product/true - Third action which returns a discounted product list.